# Unidentified Index error only for some users

Tags: php, session

Recently a strange bug has appeared and it happens only for some of the users.

I have a payment gateway where the process will look like this:

1. User enters his details and submits form.
2. Some of the details are saved as SESSION data (email included) and from those session data, everything is recorded in a DB just fine.
3. User is redirected to safe third party payment gateway. (Offsite)
4. If payment successfull user is redirected back to my server to record the transaction in my database.

This is where it gets funky.

On return, only a few of the users will have lost their SESSION data, because when I run this:

```
$all = ChargeBee_Customer::all(array(
     "email[is]" => $_SESSION["email"],
));
```

I will get a:

PHP Notice:  Undefined index: email in "Dir to file" on line 299

The code part above is Line 298,299,300

Not sure what could be the bug here, since this happens only to some of the users.

Comment: are you sure session is still active that that point? before that code check  if(!isset($_SESSION["email"])){ log somewhere entyre session} to be sure session is not empty at that point.

Comment: @LightNight that is a valid question, but then again, as I mentioned, most of the users, will have their SESSION active, because they finish this step without any problems. Only some of the users will get their SESSION data lost.

Comment: in that case, the only option I can think is time. maybe that some users took way more time to finish that step, and the session was dead at that time? canyou check that?